# TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployContract", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.1)

Tags: solidity, nodejs

```
javascript
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

async function main() {
    const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.deployContract("SimpleStorage")
    console.log("Deploying, please wait...")
    const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deployContract()
    await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment()
    console.log(
        "The contract has been deployed to",
        await SimpleStorageFactory.getAddress()
    )
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

I get this error when I try to deploy this contract using hardhat. I've tried a couple of suggestions from similar questions but it just doesn't work. does anyone know what might be the cause?

Comment: You are deploying it two times.

Comment: okay the .deploy and .deployContract are basically doing the same work, right? thank you. it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Factory be remove.

```
    const simpleStorage = await ethers.deployContract("SimpleStorage")
    console.log("Deploying, please wait...")
    await simpleStorage.waitForDeployment()
```

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/deploying